# Buscar registros de una base de datos mediante PHP y MySql

Tags: php, mysqli

Para un proyecto escolar me pidieron hacer un una pagina donde pueda buscar registros especificos en una base de datos dentro de un hosting, resulta que al intentar  hacer la consulta me arroja siempre este error:

> ```
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in 
> /home/u538782983/public_html/php/resultado.php on line 9.
> ```

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
include 'cn.php';

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
mysqli_select_db($link, $bd) or die ("Error al conectar a la base de Datos");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM registro_cbtis253 WHERE Codigo = '$codigo");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['Codigo'].$row['nombre_escuela'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59555/discussion-on-question-by-brayan-pineda-buscar-registros-de-una-base-de-datos-me).

Comment: Tu instrucción SQL tiene un error de sintaxis: `$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM registro_cbtis253 WHERE Codigo = '$codigo");`, **falta una comilla simple** después de la variable `$codigo`. De todos modos tu código es vulnerable a la Inyección SQL. Y además es incompleto... lo correcto antes del while es evaluar si no ha habido fallos en la consulta. También sería bueno que modernices el código, usando el estilo orientado a objetos en vez del estilo por procedimientos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes una errata en la query, por eso no te esta devolviendo resultados

```
<?php
include 'cn.php';

$codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
mysqli_select_db($link, $bd) or die ("Error al conectar a la base de Datos");
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM registro_cbtis253 WHERE Codigo = '$codigo' ");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['Codigo'].$row['nombre_escuela'];
}
?>
```

Falta una comilla en $codigo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba esto, si en la consulta sql primero es el `Codigo` y luego 
  `nombre_escuela` $row[0] seria codigo y $row[1] el nombre

```
 <?php
            include 'cn.php';

            $codigo = $_POST['codigo'];
            mysqli_select_db($link, $bd) or die ("Error al conectar a la base de Datos");
            $result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM registro_cbtis253 WHERE Codigo = '$codigo' ");

            while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                $cod = $row[0];
                $nom= $row[1];
            }

        ?>
```

Comment: gracais por el comentario, lo he probado y aun anda, tal vez no utilizo un metodo correcto, en fin.. seguiré investigando

Comment: intentaste sacar las comillas simples en $codigo?

Answer (score 0):

yo use

```
$registro=mysqli_query($link,"select * from productos where codpro = '$buscar'");

  if (!$registro) {
printf("problemas en consulta: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
```

}

```
 while ($ver=mysqli_fetch_array($registro))
```

Comment: Por favor, explica cual era el error y como lo solucionas.